# Как правильно реализовать совместный роутинг RoR + React

Tags: веб-программирование, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

Хочу попробовать написать приложение на серверной части RoR Api на фронте React SPA. Не понимаю как правильно реализовать роутинг на сайте. Сам бы я сделал что то типо http://api.site.ru/ И роутеры полностью совпадали с http://site.ru/ но думаю что это не совсем верно?

Comment: Когда речь идет о SPA(Single Page Application) серверные URL обычно подвязывают к _данным_ а не к страницам. Хотя тут многое зависит от выбранного механизма клиент-серверного общения (REST, socket.io, GraphQL).

Comment: REST. Где вообще про это можно почитать? Сейчас реализую так что апи находилось в папке API и фронт энд полностью повторяет роуты бэкэнда только бэкэнд в папке api

Comment: Если REST, то, очевидно, в литературе по REST =) Хотя сразу хочу вас предупредить: React - это только View из MVC. Для построения полноценного клиентского приложения вам стоит продумать как именно данные будут попадать в компоненты React. Можете посмотреть что-нибудь по модной идеологии flux/redux.

Comment: Это все понятно, интересует именно как совместить роутинг)

Comment: Эм... У SPA - всегда одна точка входа. А маршруты REST API могут быть где угодно. Вариант с дополнительным каталогом (`/api`) вполне приемлемое решение.

Answer (score 1):

Сам никогда не делал, но из тех проектов, которые видел - было просто дублирование роутов. Т.е. на фронте явно в конфигах указаны нужные роуты для апи.
Если фронт отдаётся тем же приложением, что и апи - можно автоматизировать - прирендерить жс вьюху с роутами. Если другое - можно попробовать сделать метод в АПИ для получения роутов.
Но особой прелести я в этом не вижу - только дополнительная нагрузка на бэкенд.